# Xcode builds are relying on metro bundler

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native

I developed several apps with React Native, and the build process in Xcode allowed to work them without metro bundler running across, relying on included jsbundle file.

But then I joined new project, which relies on metro bundler along Xcode build in order to make app work and exposes developer tools, even if `__DEV__` is false in JS. So, when we uploaded archived build to TestFlight app crashes after splash screen and sentry gives us no clue at all.

I'm not an iOS nor objective-c developer, so I don't even know where to start from.

React Native version is 0.53

Answer (score 5):

I'm such a dumbass

I wasn't aware of the preparing app to build process, that's described in official docs.

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device.html#building-your-app-for-production

And in order to keep thing more clear, I've duplicated existing schema and named it `myAppName (staging)` and `myAppName (production)`. Both schema builds configured as `Release`, but include different `.env` config (https://github.com/luggit/react-native-config)

Comment: but during release build process metro bundler always opening which is uncomfortable when you deploying with CI tool. How to disable metro bundler at all, during release build?

Answer (score 0):

This fixed the issue in my case

```html
//Change your ios .xcscheme code from the following
<ArchiveAction
   buildConfiguration = "Debug"
   revealArchiveInOrganizer = "YES">
</ArchiveAction>

//set the buildConfiguration to Release
<ArchiveAction
   buildConfiguration = "Release"
   revealArchiveInOrganizer = "YES">
</ArchiveAction>
```